# Heavely blurred shadows with the sun node

Tags: shadows

I'm only posting it because i never found a solution online, i just recently FINALLY found the solution to the problem, and it's so easy.

The problem:

When i used the sun node the shadows ended up looking like this!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Drag the angle value of the sun to 0

[image]

[image]